# How to optimize the PL/SQL code that uses cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, plsql, database-cursor

I am trying to optimize a query that is running for around 3 hours to fetch/update 2.8 million records. The code uses cursor and we need to update the entire set of 2.8 million records. I tried modifying the query using bulk collect but i dont think it has helped much. Could someone please advise me on what else i can do to optimize the code. To be honest i dont think it is any better at all even with bulk collect... I am using oracle19c

Old code is:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR PROVNUMCURSOR
    IS
      SELECT DISTINCT RCRD_NBR, ID, Entity FROM SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM ;
    v_FirstRow SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM.RCRD_NBR%type;
    v_ID SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM.ID%type;
    v_Entity SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM.Entity%type;
  BEGIN
    OPEN PROVNUMCURSOR;
    --v_FirstRow:=0;v_ID:=0;v_Entity:='0';
    FETCH PROVNUMCURSOR
    INTO v_FirstRow,
      v_ID,
      v_Entity;
    WHILE PROVNUMCURSOR%FOUND
    LOOP
      SELECT
        CASE
          WHEN v_ID = v_EndRow
          THEN v_MaxRow
          ELSE
            (SELECT RCRD_NBR-1 FROM SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM WHERE ID = v_ID+1
            )
        END
      INTO v_LastRow
      FROM dual;
      IF v_Entity = '3' THEN
        UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF a
        SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
          ||'I'
        WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow AND v_LastRow;
      ELSE
        IF v_Entity = '4' THEN
          UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF a
          SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
            || 'II'
          WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow AND v_LastRow;
        ELSE
          UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF a
          SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
          WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow AND v_LastRow;
        END IF;
      END IF;
      FETCH PROVNUMCURSOR INTO v_FirstRow, v_ID, v_Entity;
      EXIT
    WHEN PROVNUMCURSOR%NOTFOUND;
    END LOOP;
    --END;
    CLOSE PROVNUMCURSOR;
  END;
```

The code that i modified is the below:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR PROVNUMCURSOR
    IS
      SELECT DISTINCT RCRD_NBR,
        ID,
        Entity
      FROM SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM_TEST ;
  type v_ID_type
IS
  TABLE OF SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM_TEST.ID%type;
type v_Entity_type
IS
  TABLE OF SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM_TEST.Entity%type;
type v_FirstRow_type
IS
  TABLE OF SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM_TEST.RCRD_NBR%type;
  v_FirstRow v_FirstRow_type;
  v_ID v_ID_type;
  v_Entity v_Entity_type;
  c_limit PLS_INTEGER := 100;
BEGIN
  OPEN PROVNUMCURSOR;
  --v_FirstRow:=0;v_ID:=0;v_Entity:='0';
  LOOP
    FETCH PROVNUMCURSOR bulk collect INTO v_FirstRow, v_ID,v_Entity LIMIT C_LIMIT;
    EXIT
  WHEN V_FIRSTROW.COUNT = 0;
    --dbms_output.put_line(V_FIRSTROW.COUNT);
    FOR INDX IN 1..V_FIRSTROW.COUNT
    LOOP
      --      dbms_output.put_line(1);
      SELECT
        CASE
          WHEN v_ID(INDX) = v_EndRow
          THEN v_MaxRow
          ELSE
            (SELECT RCRD_NBR-1
            FROM SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM_TEST
            WHERE ID = v_ID(INDX)+1
            )
        END
      INTO v_LastRow
      FROM dual;
      IF v_Entity(INDX) = '3' THEN
        UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF_TEST a
        SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
          ||'I'
        WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow(INDX) AND v_LastRow;
      ELSIF v_Entity(INDX) = '4' THEN
          --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_entity || ' First Row '|| v_FirstRow || ' Last row '||v_LastRow);
          UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF_TEST a
          SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
            || 'II'
          WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow(INDX) AND v_LastRow;
        ELSE
         -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_entity || ' First Row '|| v_FirstRow || ' Last row '||v_LastRow);
          UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF_TEST a
          SET ProvNum = LTRIM(RTRIM(TO_CHAR(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))))
          WHERE RCRD_NBR BETWEEN v_FirstRow(INDX) AND v_LastRow;
        END IF;
     END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE PROVNUMCURSOR;
END;
```

```
Sample data:
RCRD_NBR    FILE_NM       PROVNUM   ID  ENTITY
225184      sample.txt              1681    2
225241      sample.txt              1682    3
225352      sample.txt              1683    4
225436      sample.txt              1684    5
225493      sample.txt               1685   2
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data. I would assume you can do it all in one single UPDATE statement. No cursor, no loop, no bulk fetch.

Comment: In addition to that, have you done any profiling to see where the time is actually being spent?  It is entirely possible, for example, that you're missing an index/ there is a trigger on the table/ there is an unindexed foreign key that is actually causing performance to be slow.

Comment: What is `v_MaxRow`? It is not declared in your code, i.e. it should not work at all.

Comment: Do you have an index on `GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF_TEST.RCRD_NBR`?

Comment: @JustinCave  The table is indexed on rcrd_nbr and there is no trigger on the table. Also, no unindexed foreign keys are there. The issue that i was able to find was with the update statement within the code that is taking a lot of time. I observed that in toad

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit v_maxrow is defined above. I havent mentioned that in the code pasted here.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I have attached sample data in the question now

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text. And then let us know desired result and the logic.

Comment: Why do you use `DISTINCT` in your query? Would not make any difference based on your sample data.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit The logic here is we are trying to populate the prov_num field which is currently empty with the value in column0 which is a column populated by a text file.
v_EndRow varibale has the last ID in it and v_MaxRow has max of rcrd_num in it. So that check is mandatory and these are getting populated in a code which i havent pasted here.

Answer (score 2):

Without having any sample data and without knowing the logic it is difficult to provide a solution. I think it could be done with a single statement which goes in a direction like this one:

```
UPDATE SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_SSB_SC_PDF a SET ProvNum =
with t as
    (SELECT DISTINCT
       RCRD_NBR as FirstRow,
       LEAD(RCRD_NBR, 1) -1 OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS LastRow,
       CASE Entity
           when '3' then TRIM(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))||'I'
           when '4' then TRIM(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))||'II'
           else TRIM(SUBSTR(Column0, 1, 13))
       end case as ProvNum
    FROM SPSMDMRW.GTT_SCW_PROFILE_INTRM)
SELECT t.ProvNum
from t
where a.RCRD_NBR BETWEEN FirstRow AND LastRow;
```